# Mocking current time for functional tests

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, cucumber, functional-testing

I am writing a functional test using cucumber for my Spring boot application. The logic which I want to test uses current time, based on that the result vary. Is there a way to mock the current time in functional tests

Comment: Yes, there are ways of mocking current time. You should probably share what are you using for retrieving current time.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible using PowerMock http://powermock.github.io/

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// ... other annotations
public class SomeTest  {

    private final Date fixedDate = new Date(10000);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Date.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(fixedDate);
    }

    ...
}
```

Another approach is to use some service that provides current time and mock this service in the test. Rough example

```
@Service
public class DateProvider {
   public Date current() { return new Date(); }
}

@Service
public class CurrentDateConsumer {
   @Autowired DateProvider dateProvider;

   public void doSomeBusiness() { 
        Date current = dateProvider.current();   
        // ... use current date   
   }
}

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class CurrentDateConsumerTest {
   private final Date fixedDate = new Date(10000);

   @Mock DateProvider dateProvider;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       when(dateProvider.current()).thenReturn(fixedDate);
   }
}
```

Comment: This wont be available when I fun my feature tests in cucumber right

Comment: @Priya, seems to. I've updated my answer for more universal solution